# How to unescape URLs in flask?

Tags: python, url, flask, werkzeug

When I route back to index with a parameter eg `app.route('/index?status=<status>')`, why is the URL escaped on the browser side?

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/index%3Fstatus%3Dfalse`

Or, more towards my question, how do I unescape the URL? And where in Flask am I able to do this? I did some googling around Flask and Werkzeug, but wasn't able to find anything...

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the query string in the route. Instead, use request.args.get to access them.

```
@app.route('/index')
    if 'status' in request.args:
        status = request.args.get('status')
```